# Clear-Site-Data header error in Chrome console and my CSS changes not reflecting

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, clear-site-data

I have ASP.net MVC application which is hosted on server.
I have some font changes on my site, so I did it on local system and it was working fine but when I put it on server the same is not reflecting and one thing, I noticed that in chrome console it is "showing Clear-Site-Data header on 'myURL/Content/bootstrap.css': Unrecognized type: 'storage" and "Clear-Site-Data header on 'myURL/Content/bootstrap.css': Unrecognized type: 'cookies'"
and when I am browsing my CSS file from browser then there, I can't find my changes there it is showing my old file even after I have replaced it with the new file.

Can anybody help to figure out what could be issue and the solution? I am a beginer developer

[image: Attaching the image for reference]

[image]